# Django - unique_together validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

Given the example code below, what would be the best way to validate that there are no duplicate `code` per `account`?

**Model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', editable=False)
    code = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('account', 'code')
```

**Form**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('code',)
```

**View**

```
def post_add(request):
    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(membership__user=request.user)
    except:
        login_url = reverse('login') + ('?next=%s') % request.path
        return HttpResponseRedirect(login_url)

    post = Post()

    if request.method == "POST":
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, prefix='post')

        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            post.account = account
            post.save()

        # other code
```

I've found answers suggesting something similar to using `clean_code()` but `account` doesn't seem to exist at that point. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Here's relevant example from documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Basically clean() has access to all fields via cleaned_data. This is for approach for validation within Form.

If you want to do it in model, look at pre_save.

Comment: Jure, I understand what you're saying but `account` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Ah, I see. In your meta:         fields = ('code',), why don't also include account? This way it will be part of the code. You can make it hidden.